# I'm not obtaining the desired URLRewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am experiencing an odd problem with URLs.  I'm using `.htaccess` and `header(location)` to set the web address.

I think that I'm "resetting" the web address at the bottom with header (location), but instead it looks like the address that I'm specifying gets appended to the current address rather than replacing it all.

My code is:

```
$route = ltrim(strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'), '/');
if($route == strtolower($route)) {

    if($route === 'contact/edit') {
            include __DIR__ . '/../myscripts/MainScript.php';
            $driver = new MainDriver();
            $page = $driver->edit();
    }elseif($route === 'contact/add' ) {
            include __DIR__ . '/../myscripts/MainScript.php';
            $driver = new MainDriver();
            $page = $driver->add();
    }else {
            include __DIR__ . '/../myscripts/MainScript.php';
            $driver = new MainDriver();
            $page = $driver->home();
    }
}else {
    http_response_code(301);
    header('location: index.php?route=' . strtolower($route));
}
```

.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/contact/edit(new|existing)$ /index.php?route=/contact/edit$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

localhost opens just fine.  But, if I try to go to `localhost/contact/editNew`, instead of taking me to `localhost/contact/editnew` I am taken to `localhost/contact/index.php?contact/editnew` and the welcome page `index.php` gets loaded!

I think the last rewrite rule is what's going to have to be modified, but I don't know for certain.  That's why I'm looking for help here.  I wrote that rule based on a mod_rewrite page on apache.org that I read.

Let me know if you need more details to understand this issue.

(EDIT#2)

I have edited the header call to

```
header('location: ' . strtolower($route);
```

And I still obtain the same result, which confirms that the problem is caused by the URLRewrite rule that I'm learning now.  Do you folks know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues with the code you posted...

> ```
> http_response_code(301);
> header('location: index.php?route=' . strtolower($route));
> ```

You are passing a *relative* URL in the `Location` header. The *browser* is going to resolve this relative to the current URL. If the requested URL is `/contact/editNew` then the above will result in a redirect to `/contact/index.php?route=<route>`.

The URL you set in the `Location` should at least be root-relative (starting with a slash), or absolute (preferable).

This is also a 301 (permanent) redirect so will be persistently cached by the browser. (*Test* with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.)

You are redirecting to a query string `route=<route>`, which you are also trying to do in one of your `RewriteRule` directives. However, your PHP script is only configured to parse the URL-path - the query string is stripped from the request to calculate the route:

> ```
> $route = ltrim(strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'), '/');
> ```

This retrieves the part of the URL *before* the query string and *discards* the query string. It also trims the `/` from the start of the URL-path, making it *relative*. So, again, if you later used `header('location: ' . strtolower($route));` - you would have the same problem as mentioned above.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^/contact/edit(new|existing)$ /index.php?route=/contact/edit$1 [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

The second rule does not appear to serve any purpose? With the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and this appearing after the rewrite to `/index.php` it's not going to do anything anyway.

But neither does it need to do anything, at least not according to your PHP script. Your PHP script looks at the URL-path on the *requested URL*. It's not looking at the rewritten URL or query string.

Minor points, but the `NC` and `QSA` flags on the first `RewriteRule` are superfluous, and the regex could be simplified to just a dot. And the slash prefix on the *substitution* string is not required. For example:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If you simply, want to convert all URLs to lowercase then you could do this in `.htaccess`, *before* your existing directives:

```
# Convert URL to lowercase.
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

---

**UPDATE:** Maybe you're wanting to pass the requested URL-path as a query string to your script? However, as noted, your PHP is currently using the URL-path, not the query string.

For example, your `.htaccess` would be like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Your PHP script will now receive the `route` as part of the query string. Which you can examine using the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` or `$_GET['route']` superglobals in your PHP script. Or/and, you can still examine the requested URL-path, which you are currently doing, to provide two methods to access your pages.

Note, with the above rewrite, the `route` URL-parameter will not be present on requests to the home page, since that is handled by the `DirectoryIndex` (mod_dir).

Comment: Thank for your answer, MrWhite.  I'm a mod_rewrite newbie.  So, that's the main reason I'm trying to get this issue sorted out here.  My script is supposed to be looking at the rewritten URL, and I thought I was, but since I'm new to this I just don't know how to do this.  Can either you or Amit explain to me how I can pick up the rewritten URL so I can incorporate that into my PHP script?

Comment: You don't normally want (or need) to look at the rewritten URL in your PHP script. Indeed your whole PHP script is currently geared towards examining the requested URL (the URL the user actually requested), not the rewritten URL. Your `.htaccess` file consists of a front-controller pattern, where you rewrite all requests to `index.php`. If you examine the rewritten URL then all you will see is `index.php`, which is not particularly helpful. (?)

Comment: You seem to already have a "working" system, except for the issues I mentioned above. Maybe you want to look at the query string instead? (Although that's not how your current PHP script is configured.) But this doesn't really offer any benefit and imposes some additional restrictions.

Comment: I think I understand.  I'm happy to report now that my script is working.  Thank you all so much for having taken the time to help me sort this out.

Comment: @xsundevil I've updated my answer with an alternative version that passes the route as a query string, with a bit of info as to how you access this in your PHP script. However, this is not necessary any better than what you were doing before.

Comment: I used to be getting the method and controller to be called using $_GET['controller'] and $_GET['action'].  But, I gave that up (because of security issues) in favor of a single URL variable (a route).  This is better as users could now instantiate a controller and call a method, but ONLY if it's in the list of if statements - like in my script. I called the route "contact/edit" just to give these pages an identifier (the "contact" part is the identifier).

Comment: Anyhow, the source that I learned URL Rewriting from used it as another reason for using a single route variable instead of the insecure controller and action variables.  It says that you can configure your web server so that when someone visits /contact/edit, it actually runs index.php?route=contact/edit and the requested URL will still be shown in the browser's address bar.  BUT(!), for some reason it forgot to mention anything about QUERY_STRING.  It only mentioned REQUEST_URI...

Comment: I'm having problems again.  I tried to figure it out for myself, but it's very confusing.  I have a question for you.  When you say, "your PHP script looks at the URL-path on the requested URL.  It's not looking at the rewritten URL or query string."  How do I fix my script so that it looks at the rewritten URL or query string?